# Q-promises and error handling

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, q

I am trying to understand Q Promises and how to handle two different errors thrown from two different then blocks.

Here is the function I would like to "Promisfy":

```
router.post('/user', function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body);
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(error, foundUser) {
    if(foundUser) {
      res.send("Error: User with email " + foundUser.email + " already exists.", 409);
    } else {
      User.create(user, function(err, createdUser) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err, 400);
        } else {
          res.json({ id: createdUser.id }, 201);
        }
      });
    }
  });  
});
```

It takes some User details, and tries to create a new User if one doesn't exist already with the same email. If one does, send a 409. I also handle the normal mongoose error with a 400.

I've tried using mongoose-q to convert it over, and I end up with this:

```
router.post('/user', function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body);
  User.findOneQ({email : req.body.email})
  .then(function(existingUser) {
    if (existingUser) {
      res.send("Error: User with email " + existingUser.email + " already exists.", 409);
    } 
    return User.create(user);
  })
  .then(function(createdUser) { 
    res.json({ id: createdUser.id }, 201); 
  })
  .fail(function(err) { 
    res.send(err, 400)
  })
});
```

Is this correct? Is there anyway to push that existing user check into a fail block? I.e. throw an Error, and then catch it and deal with it?

Something like this perhaps:

```
router.post('/user', function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body);
  User.findOneQ({email : req.body.email})
  .then(function(existingUser) {
    if (existingUser) {
      throw new Error("Error: User with email " + existingUser.email + " already exists.");
    } 
    return User.create(user);
  })
  .then(function(createdUser) { 
    res.json({ id: createdUser.id }, 201); 
  })
  .fail(function(duplicateEmailError) {
    res.send(duplicateEmailError.message)
  })
  .fail(function(mongoError) { 
    res.send(mongoError, 400)
  })
});
```

Comment: Your original code has a bug, it doesn't check if `error` happened after .findOne :<

Comment: Mongoose already returns promises if you call `.exec`

Comment: Good pickup both of you, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not experienced enough with Q. However, I can answer with bluebird.

[bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) supports *typed* catches. Which means you can create new Error subclasses, throw them, and handle them accordingly.

I've used `newerror` in my example to simplify the creation of Error subclasses.

```
var newerror = require('newerror');

var DuplicateEmailError = newerror('DuplicateEmailError');

router.post('/user', function(req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    User.findOneAsync({ email: req.body.email }).then(function(existingUser) {
        if (existingUser) {
            throw new DuplicateEmailError('Error: User with email ' + existingUser.email + ' already exists.');
        }

        return User.createAsync(user);
    }).then(function(createdUser) {
        res.json({ id: createdUser.id }, 201);
    }).catch(DuplicateEmailError, function(err) {
        res.send(err.message, 409);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        res.send(err.message, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: btw the DuplicateEmailError won't have any .message

Comment: @Esailija indeed. Fixed it :)

Comment: Q does not support typed catches, you'd have to perform a `if(err instanceof){` check inside the .catch

Comment: That kind of sucks. Hmm what other approaches should I be using for errors?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra just drop Q and use bluebird, what's the problem? :D

Comment: Fair call. Will have a look